# Navigation controller, used to update navbar values, only gets called once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a very simple Angular app in order to learn the ropes.

I'm using Yeoman's `angular-generator` for scaffolding, which uses a predefined `.config` with `$routeProvider`, that I adapted to my needs as follows:

```
angular
  .module('raidersApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/:langID/:proverbID', {
        templateUrl: 'views/proverb.html',
        controller: 'ProverbCtrl'
      })
      .when('/:langID', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/en'
      });
  });
```

I created several templates to be included in my app's `index.html` in an attempt to keep things organized, as follows:

```
<header class="header" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
  <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
</header>

<main class="container">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>
</footer>
```

Within the header view, I have a simple Bootstrap navbar with values that I would want to update based on user input, namely the ID (or name) of the selected language, which is obtained through `$routeParams`:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{langID}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#/{{language}}" ng-repeat="language in languages">{{language}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I created a `data` factory to store this value and make it accessible to more than one controller:

```
angular.module('raidersApp')
  .factory('data', function () {

    var langID = "en";

    return {
      getLang: function() {
        return langID;
      },
      setLang: function(newlangID) {
        langID = newlangID;
      }
    }

  });
```

I also created a separate controller, `HeaderCtrl`, to handle the navbar:

```
angular.module('raidersApp')
  .controller('HeaderCtrl', function (data, $http, $scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.langID = data.getLang();
    $scope.languages = [
      'en',
      'pt',
      'se'
    ];
  });
```

However, this controller is getting called only **once**. Which means that whichever language or `langID` is set as the default by my service (in this case, `"en"`), will always be the value that my navbar displays on the dropdown menu, never to be updated again.

Everything else works as expected (The URLs do work, and the selected language is in fact updated through `$routeParams` on my main controller, just not on the header controller).

I suspect this has to do with the fact that my `HeaderCtrl` is being defined outside of the scope of the `ng-view`, as seen in the `index.html` snippet above, and so my app's `$routeProvider` will happily ignore it forever while caring only about the controllers defined within it.

How can I go about solving this problem without having to repeat the navbar in each and every one of the views that I would want in my app?

I thought about using `ng-include` in every template, but that too, feels dirty.

Is there a "cleaner" or more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, change this line:

```
$scope.langID = data.getLang();
```

to

```
$scope.langID = function () {
    return data.getLang();
}
```

Then change the binding in your header to:

`{{langID()}}`

This will cause it to get the value from the factory on every $digest.

What I believe is happening here is that the controller is setting your $scope.langID to the value of data.getLang();

data.getLang()'s value changes, but your scope variable won't. Wrap it in a function instead and it should work as expected.

Comment: Actually, the way he has it will work - but it will only work once, when the controller is first instantiated.  You would still need to call the function each time to get the updated value.

Comment: right, it will have the initial value, but once data.getLang() changes, it won't update the navbar controller's scope variable. That is why he would need to wrap it in a function, to solve his problem with the navbar not updating.

Comment: What is calling the function?

Comment: he Has {{langID}} in his navbar template. He'd need to change it to {{ langID() }}

Comment: +1
Simple solution.  I am curious about the cost of doing this.  I am sure one binding like this is no big deal, but if it were many it could be a bad thing, just like too many watchers are.  You get a minimum of two $digests every cycle.

Comment: Performance won't change significantly, as your current $scope variable is already being watched by Angular. Also, the function to get language won't be called, unless the value changes on your factory. If your user does not switch languages, that function will only get called once initially.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to set the $scope.language property every time the value updates, one way you could do it is to set a $watch on the value in the factory.  Whenever it changes, you can have your header controller grab the new value.  Here is some example code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">Language: {{language}}</div>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"><button ng-click="randomNum()">Set</button></div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.randomNum = function() {
    myFactory.set(Math.random())
    console.log(myFactory.get())
  }

});

app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.language ='';
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return myFactory.get()}, 
    function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if(newVal != oldVal) {
        $scope.language = newVal;
      }
    })

})

app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  var myVal = '';
  return {
    get: function() {
      return myVal;
    },
    set: function(val) {
      myVal = val;
    }
  }
})
```

Essentially, whenever we click the button attached to `MainCtrl`, it sets a random value to the factory's `myVal`.  But `HeaderCtrl` has no way of knowing that the value has changed unless we manually call (or set an interval - don't do that) the factory get function again.  We create a $watch function that checks to see if the value in the factory changes, and then if it does we can trigger some additional logic - in this case we want the new value.

Another solution would be to do a $rootScope.$broadcast from the first controller and set up a $scope.$on listener on the second controller.  Whenever that listener fires we can tell it to do a get from the factory.

I am not aware of either solution being necessarily better than the other, though I think the one I have proposed here involves a little less code.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kohcs3LqXL8y6sqacicu?p=preview)